# Width of Select is not constant

Tags: html, css

```css
.form-fluid select {
    max-width: 99.5%;
    width: 99.5%;
}


select {
    height: 24px;
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 12px;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -ms-border-radius: 0;
    -o-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 1px solid #dfcea0;
}
```

Width of select box is not same.
Once it is narrow and another time it is broad. How to have a constant width whenever i click.
[this is first one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzuOp.png)

[this is second time, which i dont want it to be like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsII5.png)

Comment: Hi, try to create working demo or add html and css code.

Comment: Can you provide us with some code? How I understand it you can use `max-width: 200px;` or`min-width: 200px;` or something like that in your CSS file.

Comment: Are the values in each select box completely the same?

Answer (score 0):

Style the selectbox so it has a width.

Example:

```
<select style="width:100px">
  <option>this is a very long option</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have set max-width and width in percent, which takes into account the width of its parent container, and get sets accordingly,
you need to set it in pixel if you want the same size on every screen, or if you don't want to set fix pixel, then give padding to the select

**min/max width**

```
.form-fluid select {
    max-width: 200px;
    min-width:200px;
}
```

**padding**

```
.form-fluid select {
  padding: 0px 40px;
}
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dohsoL53/1/) for mix/max

Answer (score -1):

Create like this way.

**Html**

```
 <select class="demo">
     <option>Testing</option>
     <option>Testing</option>
     <option>Testing TestingTesting Testing Testing</option>
 </select>
```

**css**

```
.demo{width:200px}
```

Here you can change the width of the box as per your requirement.Here you can also used the **max-width**/**min-width** and **width** if you wanted to restricted box size.

Comment: It would be good if you will provide reason what's wrong in above code. So we will improve quality of the code.